# React native - Invalid state update warning

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The following code produces a Warning 'Cant perform a React State update in an unmounted component.  This is a no-op, but it indicated a memory leak in your application..'

I'm new to RN - working my way through my first build - I cant understand why this error is being produced as I am not calling any stae changes until componentDidMount - can anyone offer any tips please?

```
Class CheckIn extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      venue: undefined,
      checkinTime:0,
      currentLocation:null,
    };
  }
  getCurrentCoordinates = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        const currentLongitude = JSON.stringify(position.coords.longitude);
        const currentLatitude = JSON.stringify(position.coords.latitude);
        const currentLocation = currentLatitude + ',' + currentLongitude;
        this.setState({ currentLocation });
        this.getCurrentTime();
      },
      error => Alert.alert(error.message),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
    );
  };
  minutes_with_leading_zeros=(dt)=>
  {
    return (dt.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + dt.getMinutes();
  }
  getCurrentTime = () => {
    const dt = new Date();
    const dtcur = dt.getHours() +':' +this.minutes_with_leading_zeros(dt);

    this.setState({
      checkinTime: dtcur,
    });

  };

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getCurrentCoordinates();
    this.getCurrentTime();
  }
```

Comment: navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition registers a listener which will call your lambda function even when the component is unmounted. You have to unregister it on componentWillUnMount()

Comment: You calling the `getCurrentTime` from `componentDidMount` and `getCurrentCoordinates `, keep in one maybe? Then watch the `getCurrentCoordinates` from  `componentWillMount`?
Also CheckIn component doing anything else? maybe thats why its calling `componentWillUnMount` inbetween setState?

Comment: Cheers guys @CodySwann - any tips how i would unregister the listener?